# Using Multiple Ranges as a Single Criteria Excel

Tags: excel

If I am using the =SUMIF() Function in excel which is specified as =SUMIF(range, criteria, sum_range)

If I would like to specify two different range sets for both the range and sum_range but would like for them to act as single criteria,

```
 =SUMIF((A7:A17,A20:A30),"3",(B7:B17,B20:B30))
```

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: If `=SUMIF()+SUMIF()` doesn't work for you.  Post the data you have and what you want to accomplish, and we can help you out.

Comment: The data is not continuous in the column hence the need for multiple ranges. If you look at the example ranges I provided in my question you will see that for the range values I am not interested in the values of A18 or A19 and for the sum_range values I am not interested in the B18 or B19 values. I cannot include them because that data is not related to what I would like to analyze, that is why i would like to skip over those values but in a way combine the multiple ranges into a single range criteria.

Comment: What I meant is to use a formula like this: `=SUMIF((A7:A17),3,(B7:B17))+SUMIF((A20:A30),3,(B20:B30))`.  You can make ranges so this formula can be changed dynamically.  Otherwise, you will want to use `SUMPRODUCT` for a more complicated scenario.